# Installing Avogadro 1.2.0 From Source Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, compiling, cmake

Package downloaded as avogadro-1.2.0.tar.gz and put in the home/src folder; extracted to the same folder.  I got as far as step 2 from the INSTALL folder, here ...

```
Requirements
============
 -- CMake 2.8.9 or later (2.8.11 recommended)
 -- Qt 4.6.0 or later (4.8.5 recommended)
 -- OpenBabel 2.3.x or later (development version from 
  http://github.org/openbabel/openbabel is recommended)
 -- Eigen 2.0.x or later (3.x also supported)


Basic Installation
==================
These instructions give a very basic overview of how to configure, compile and
install Avogadro on most systems.  If you are using unique install locations
and/or libraries are not automatically detected please consult the 'Advanced'
section.

1. Create a 'build' directory in the package source directory.

   mkdir build
   cd build

2. Configure the build system

   cmake ../

3. Compile

   make -j2

4. Install

   sudo make install
```

that is, after typing

```
cmake ../
```

I got the following errors,

```
darren@darren-Vostro-3560:~/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build$  cmake ../
-- The build type is RelWithDebInfo
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1314 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:226 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/darren/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/darren/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

with the CMakeOutput.log saying, snipped since too long but can be supplied.

and the CMakeError.log saying,

```
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test COMPILES_WITHOUT_FPERMISSIVE failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/darren/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_842a7/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_842a7.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_842a7.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/darren/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_842a7.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DCOMPILES_WITHOUT_FPERMISSIVE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_842a7.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/darren/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/home/darren/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:6:17: error: declaration of ‘auto_ptr<_Tp> counted_ptr<_Tp>::auto_ptr()’ changes meaning of ‘auto_ptr’ [-fpermissive]
    6 |   auto_ptr<_Tp> auto_ptr();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/darren/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:2:28: note: ‘auto_ptr’ declared here as ‘class auto_ptr<_Tp>’
    2 | template <class _Tp> class auto_ptr {};
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_842a7.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_842a7.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/darren/src/avogadro-1.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_842a7/fast] Error 2


Source file was:

template <class _Tp> class auto_ptr {};
template <class _Tp>
struct counted_ptr
{
  auto_ptr<_Tp> auto_ptr();
};
int main() {return 0;}
```

and me saying, please help.

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). The package if maintained should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) before now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avogadro 1.2 requires Qt4, which has been deprecated as Qt5 is available. You can directly install (without compiling) a newer (1.93.0) version of Avogadro with the command

```
sudo apt install avogadro
```

---

If you really need the old version, first install Qt4 from the Rock Core Team [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4/) (Please note that I have not tested it, so use at your own risk. However, there has been 50000+ [downloads](https://ppa-stats.sheth.io/#/?ppaName=qt4&ppaOwner=rock-core&packageName=libqtgui4) from this PPA, so it is probably safe.).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt update
```

Then install the Qt4 libraries with

```
sudo apt install qt4-x11 libqt4-dev
```

Now proceed with `cmake ../` once again.

Comment: But doesn't sudo apt install avogadro install avogadro2 ?

Comment: @DarrenRhodes According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/avogadro, it installs 1.93.0 (I don't know if 1.93.0 is branded as avogadro2).

Comment: Yes, 1.93 is Avogadro2 and this hastily introduction of Avogadro2 has derailed too much science... I resorted to using a VM with old Avogadro, by the way. Sorry developers, Avogadro2 is a great piece of software but just not yet ready for production environment.

Comment: @EsmuIgors Has the quality improved in version 1.97 in ubuntu 23.04?